# Error. Unrecognized selector to instance. (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've been looking at similar questions, but I still don't understand where I'm going wrong in my situation. Getting this error:

```
MyAwesomeApp[3481:1330310] -[Session setClient:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e05de0
2015-03-15 07:30:29.990 MyAwesomeApp[3481:1330310] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Session setClient:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e05de0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x28e1045f 0x36ca6c8b 0x28e15879 0x28e13797 0x28d45008 0x646c4 0x628b4 0x62ba4 0x2c35de7f 0x2c4c1b35 0x2c35de7f 0x2c35de21 0x2c348c43 0x2c35d88d 0x2c35d567 0x2c356e31 0x2c32d759 0x2c5a12f9 0x2c32c1a9 0x28dd6fbf 0x28dd63cf 0x28dd4a35 0x28d223b1 0x28d221c3 0x3034f201 0x2c38c43d 0xa7a24 0xa7a60 0x37232aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

When I execute this code:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if session != nil {
            editSession()
        } else {
            createSession()
        }

        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }

func editSession() {
        session?.sessionTitle = sessionTitleTxt.text
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
    }

func createSession() {
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Session", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let newSession = Session(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        if sessionTitleTxt.text == "" {
            newSession.sessionTitle = "Untitled Session"

        } else {
            newSession.sessionTitle = sessionTitleTxt.text
            newSession.client = self.client!
        }

        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
        SessionsTVC?.client = newSession.client

    }
```

Session class is:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Session)
class Session: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var sessionDate: String
@NSManaged var sessionTitle: String
@NSManaged var sessionNotes: String
@NSManaged var sessionExercises: NSSet

@NSManaged var client: Client

}
```

Can anyone help me out? I was getting a nil for the client variable before because I have several segues that I had confused, but now I'm getting this selector error and not sure how to move forward.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Show the definition of your Session class

Comment: Added Session managed object class

Comment: Was it automatically generated, or you wrote it manually?

Comment: It was generated and I added the @objc(Session)

Comment: about a year ago I added a link to the article [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) to the [ios tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/info). every ios-developer should read it imho, because it is essential information that teaches you how to debug crashes. Not only that, it also teaches you what you need to do in order to explain a crash to someone so that he can help you. tl;dr: without a proper backtrace its hard to do anything. - from what I see in your case, it seems that the `client` property is readonly...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting,

```
MyAwesomeApp[3481:1330310] -[Session setClient:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e05de0
2015-03-15 07:30:29.990 MyAwesomeApp[3481:1330310] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Session setClient:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e05de0'
```

happens when a method that is to be executed cannot be found. This can be thrown either because a method does not exist, or it is being called on the wrong object. In your specific case, the method `setClient`is being called on the `Session` object, which is being stored at the memory address of `0x16e05de0`

Make sure that the setClient method exists and is supposed to be called on that Session object.

Here is a good link to help you with debugging:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Is setClient being called when the newSession.client = self.client! line is executed from the createSession function? I have added breakpoints per your articles instructions and the two offending lines of code are the aforementioned as well as SessionTVC?.client = newSession.client. If I get rid of those two lines the app functions properly aside from the fact that I no longer am invoking the one to many client to session relationship. I still don't quite understand what's wrong with that as I've done similar relationships like that before just fine.